# Zip old builds in jenkins plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

There is some Jenkins plugin to ZIP old builds? I don't want to package just the generated archive (I am deleting those). I want to ZIP just the log data and the data used by tools, like FindBugs, Checkstyle, Surefire, Cobertura, etc.

Currently I am running out of disk space due to Jenkins. There are some build log files that reach 50 Mb due running 3000+ unit tests (most of these are severely broken builds full of stacktraces in which everything fails). But this happens frequently in some of my projects, so I get this for every bad build. Good builds are milder and may get up to around 15 Mb, but that is still a bit costly.

The surefile XML files for these are huge too. Since they tend to contain very repetitive data, I could save a lot of disk space by zipping them. But I know no Jenkins plugin for this.

Note: I am already deleting old builds not needed anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'Compress Buildlog' plugin does pretty much exactly what you're asking for, for the logs themselves at least.
https://github.com/daniel-beck/compress-buildlog-plugin

For everything else, you'll probably want an unconditional step after your build completes that manually applies compression to other generated files that will stick around.

Comment: This plugin is one year newer than my 3 year old question. Thanks anyway, but nowadays I am not working with that old project anymore (I am barely able to even remember it). Due to that, it won't be easy to evaluate if this would be the solution for that old issue or not, but I will examine this closer nonetheless.

Comment: Looking to the code, it seems to be exactly what I'd needed at those days and very spot on. I have no means to test this nowadays, but thank you very much for pointing this out.

Comment: Wow, thanks for actually coming back to look and change the accepted answer. Most people don't bother.

Answer (score 2):

The [administering Jenkins guide](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins) gives some guidance on how to do this manually. There are also links to the following plugins

- [Shelve Project](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Shelve+Project+Plugin)
- [thinBackup](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/thinBackup)

The last one is really designed to backup Jenkins configuration, but there are also options for build results.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But unfortunately this does not solves my problem. Shelve deletes the entire project (it just happens to be a delete with an undelete option), so I can't archive a particular build without deleting everything else and can't show an old build without unarchiving everything. The guide does not helps too, being similar to what Shelve proposes. thinBackup was not designed for archiving builds, and forcing it to do so would be hard, hackish and slow at best. Further it has a lot of issues when it decides to stop the world for its purposes blowing up the very idea of CI.

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is early 3 years ago there may be other people search the same question

here is my answer

1. If you want to compress the current build job's log using [This jenkins plugin](https://github.com/daniel-beck/compress-buildlog-plugin)
2. If you want to compress the old jenkins jobs using the following script mtime +5 means the file change time is 5 days ago

   `cd "$JENKINS_HOME/jobs"
   find * -name "log" -mtime +5|xargs gzip -9v '{}'`